# How to get the absolute position of a vertex in three.js?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

As far as I know `var point = object.geometry.vertices[i];` will return with the relative position for the `x`, `y` and `z` of the point inside the geometry of the object.

How to get the absolute position, if the object was moved, rotated or scaled?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can get the world position of a vertex like so:

```js
const vertex = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once and reuse

const attribute = object.geometry.getAttribute( 'position' );

vertex.fromBufferAttribute( attribute, index );

object.localToWorld( vertex );
```

three.js r151

Comment: Newer threejs versions might sometimes use buffergeometry for better performance which does not have an verticies attribute

Comment: The value is wrong if the mesh is transformed by skeleton.

Answer (score 26):

Recent versions of Three.js (v50+) provide this functionality built into [the `THREE.Object3D` class](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=object3d#api/en/core/Object3D). In particular, to get the world coordinates of a local `THREE.Vector3` instance named `vector`, use [the `localToWorld` method](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=object3d#api/en/core/Object3D.localToWorld):

```
object.localToWorld( vector );
```

Similarly, there is [a `worldToLocal` method](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=object3d#api/en/core/Object3D.worldToLocal) for converting world coordinates into local coordinates, which is slightly more complicated, mathematically speaking. To translate a world `vector` into the objects local coordinate space:

```
object.worldToLocal( vector );
```

Comment: ...and don't forget to run object.updateMatrixWorld(); I was scratching my head for a while before I tried that.

Comment: Tried doing that... Still get 0, 0, 0 :(

Comment: I’m also totally stuck with this as well!! Spent 5 hrs trying everything here in different ways...nothing, errors, undefined...seriously frustrating!!!