# Interpolated surface in Three.js

Tags: javascript, plot, three.js, surface

**Hi folks,**

I've got a question belongig surfaces in Three.js:
I got a bunch of Vec3 Points and want want to interpolate a surface through them. While searching, I stumbeled across beziers ([three.js bezier](https://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/core/Curve.js.html) - only as lines) and what looked more like I was searching : [three.js Nurbs](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_nurbs.html). I've tried to reconstruct the code, but the documentation was terrible (pages like [this](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/ParametricGeometry)) and I didn't get how everything worked by reconstructing the code...

So here's the question:
Is there any easy way to get a shape out of my calculated points? (I would still be happy, if it's not interpolated).

Thank you guys!

Mat

Edit: What I want to acchieve is a surface plot. I stumbeled across http://acko.net/blog/making-mathbox/ but it's way too big for my needs...

Comment: Do you mean create a terrain mesh from 3D points via Delaunay Triangulation? https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki/Make-terrain-mesh-with-Delaunay-triangulation

Comment: @WestLangley yeah something like this, but would be greater if it's interpolated

Comment: The surface would be "linearly interpolated" between the points. If you set your vertex normals properly, and used `THREE.SmoothShading`, the surface would appear to be smooth. If you want your surface to be actually smooth, then you would have to create a more detailed mesh using some other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some try and error I found a solution: add a plane and than transform the single vertices.

```
// need to setup 'step', 'xStart', 'xEnd', 'yStart', 'yEnd'

// calc the variables
var width = Math.abs(-xStart+xEnd),
    height = Math.abs(-yStart+yEnd);

var stepsX = width*step, stepsY = height*step;

var posX = (xStart+xEnd)/2;
var posZ = (yStart+yEnd)/2;

// add a plane and morph it to a function
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( width, height, stepsX - 1, stepsY - 1 );
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2 ) );

var size = stepsX * (stepsY), 
    data = new Float32Array( size );

var count = 0, scope = {};

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { 
    side : THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true,
    shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
    opacity : _opacity }));


mesh.updateMatrixWorld();

// calc y value for every vertice
for ( var i = 0; i < size; i ++ ) {
    // calculate the current values
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495089/how-to-get-the-absolute-position-of-a-vertex-in-three-js
    var vector = mesh.geometry.vertices[i].clone();
    vector.applyMatrix4( 
        mesh.matrixWorld
        );
    // set them into the scope
    scope.x = vector.x + posX;
    scope.y = vector.z + posZ;
    // calculate point and write it in a temp array
    data[i] = math.eval(term, scope);
}

// push the new vertice data
for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
    geometry.vertices[ i ].y = data[ i ];
}

// update the new normals
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();

// add to scene
scene.add( mesh );
```

Only issue is that it is not working for non static functions like `tan(x)`. This snippet is using [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) to calc the term.

Greetings Mat

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Any chance you have the whole page as a gist or otherwise floating around online? Would be nice to just run this and break it apart to understand how the whole thing works, w/ Three.js etc

Comment: Hey, I think I used it here: http://math.zumschlenker.de/ the code is online here: https://github.com/schlenger/math-editor