# Vertices coordinates geometry after moving in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am beginner in 3d manipulation and in Three.js. I need to understand how to get vertices coordinates updated after I move a geometry. I tried to write this code below but it returns me the original coordinates and not those updated to the new position.

```
for(var j=0 ; j<geometryContainer.length ; j++) {               
    for (var i=0 ; i<geometryContainer[j].geometry.vertices.length ; i++){
        console.log(geometryContainer[j].geometry.vertices[i].x,// vertices coordinates do not update to new position
        geometryContainer[j].geometry.vertices[i].y,
        geometryContainer[j].geometry.vertices[i].z);
        console.log(geometryContainer[0].geometry.vertices[0].x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11495621/2940964

Answer (score 1):

you might take a look at the verticesNeedUpdate methode on the Geometry Object.
You might also need to update normals / face normals

[Threejs geometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry)