# Three JS - Find all points where a mesh intersects a plane

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have created a three.js scene that includes a plane that intersects a mesh. What I would like to do is get an array of points for all locations where an edge of the mesh crosses the plane. I have had a good look for solutions and can't seem to find anything.

Here is an image of what I currently have:

[image]

And here I have highlighted the coordinates I am trying to gather:

[image]

If anybody can point me in the right direction, that would be most appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is not the ultimate solution. This is just a point where you can start from.

**UPD: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46811485/4045502) is an extension of this answer, how to form *contours* from given points.**

Also, it's referred to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11495089/4045502) with awesome anwers from WestLangley and Lee Stemkoski about the `.localToWorld()` method of `THREE.Object3D()`.

Let's imagine that you want to find points of intersection of a usual geometry (for example, `THREE.DodecahedronGeometry()`).

[image]

The idea:

1. `THREE.Plane()` has the `.intersectLine ( line, optionalTarget )` method
2. A mesh contains faces (`THREE.Face3()`)
3. Each face has `a, b, c` properties, where indices of vertices are stored.
4. When we know indices of vertices, we can get them from the array of `vertices`
5. When we know coordinates of vertices of a face, we can build three `THREE.Line3()` objects
6. When we have three lines, we can check if our plane intersects them.
7. If we have a point of intersection, we can store it in an array.
8. Repeat steps 3 - 7 for each face of the mesh

Some explanation with code:

We have `plane` which is `THREE.PlaneGeometry()` and `obj` which is `THREE.DodecahedronGeometry()`

So, let's create a `THREE.Plane()`:

```
var planePointA = new THREE.Vector3(),
  planePointB = new THREE.Vector3(),
  planePointC = new THREE.Vector3();

var mathPlane = new THREE.Plane();
plane.localToWorld(planePointA.copy(plane.geometry.vertices[plane.geometry.faces[0].a]));
plane.localToWorld(planePointB.copy(plane.geometry.vertices[plane.geometry.faces[0].b]));
plane.localToWorld(planePointC.copy(plane.geometry.vertices[plane.geometry.faces[0].c]));
mathPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(planePointA, planePointB, planePointC);
```

Here, three vertices of any face of `plane` are co-planar, thus we can create `mathPlane` from them, using the `.setFromCoplanarPoints()` method.

Then we'll loop through faces of our `obj`:

```
var a = new THREE.Vector3(),
  b = new THREE.Vector3(),
  c = new THREE.Vector3();

  obj.geometry.faces.forEach(function(face) {
    obj.localToWorld(a.copy(obj.geometry.vertices[face.a]));
    obj.localToWorld(b.copy(obj.geometry.vertices[face.b]));
    obj.localToWorld(c.copy(obj.geometry.vertices[face.c]));
    lineAB = new THREE.Line3(a, b);
    lineBC = new THREE.Line3(b, c);
    lineCA = new THREE.Line3(c, a);
    setPointOfIntersection(lineAB, mathPlane);
    setPointOfIntersection(lineBC, mathPlane);
    setPointOfIntersection(lineCA, mathPlane);
  });
```

where

```
var pointsOfIntersection = new THREE.Geometry();
...
var pointOfIntersection = new THREE.Vector3();
```

and

```
function setPointOfIntersection(line, plane) {
  pointOfIntersection = plane.intersectLine(line);
  if (pointOfIntersection) {
    pointsOfIntersection.vertices.push(pointOfIntersection.clone());
  };
}
```

In the end we'll make our points visible:

```
var pointsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: .5,
    color: "yellow"
  });
var points = new THREE.Points(pointsOfIntersection, pointsMaterial);
scene.add(points);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/8uxw667m/) example. Press the button there to get the points of intersection between the plane and the dodecahedron.

Comment: Nice. Might as well connect the dots... https://jsfiddle.net/8uxw667m/4/

Comment: @WestLangley Yes, great! I really forgot to add such an obvious visual thing. Thanks!

Comment: nice solution. I considered about how to decide a point(intersected point) between two points, now, it seems not necessary.

Comment: Very nice. Really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @user1961104 you're welcome ) your question is very interesting )

Comment: Hey, your idea is great and helped me a lot as well. What if I would create a closed shape (polygon or triangulated shape) from these points? I tried it: I sorted the segment to get closed polygons (does not work always well). When the cut solid contains holes, then begins the pain. So is there a possibility to get a triangulated shape from these cloud of points?

Comment: @Swisx It worth a new question;) Even two questions. One is about how to find which contour is the main contour, and which is a hole in the main contour. And another one is about how to create shapes from points. Have you had a look at that that [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46811485/4045502) about how to form contours from points?

Comment: Yes, @prisoner849 I have already implemented the contour, the problem is that those segments are not sorted, so I sorted them with an own algorithm, with works with simples geometries (only contiguous lines). As soon as a point is not connected to the other, then begin the problems :)

Comment: @prisoner849 I already asked a similar question for the second problem, but no luck till now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48169143/how-to-get-a-polygon-from-a-triangulated-face-in-three-js. How to make a shape from the sorted points is easy, how to sort those points is the difficult task. Unless you make first a polygon with the segment and the triangulate it.

Comment: @prisoner849 For the first question (main contour and holes contour) is enough to use a point-in-poly algorithm. Another approach for me is this one https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/qo869tb3/, what I really need are the faces of the clipped shape in the example in the link. Sorry for the long comment  :)

Comment: @Swisx _the problem is that those segments are not sorted_ If you take a look at that [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46811485/4045502), then you'll find that it solves this issue (that solution is based on the current one and extends it). It groups points in contours. No segments there.

Comment: @prisoner849 oh ... I have not seen that part, I really oversaw it. OPS ^^
yeah, that looks very nice. Can I use that contour to do a shape like this?
`var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.triangulateShape ( contour);`
if yes it might work for a part, but still remains the issue with holes  :)
but thanks for making me aware of the last part :)

Comment: @Swisx hmm... to get a geometry from `THREE.Shape()` (when you already have got its main contour and holes), you can use `THREE.ShapeGeometry()` or `THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry()`.

Comment: thank you very much, it helped a lot even though the some properties are not available anymore. Especially fiddle example was making it more understandable

Answer (score 3):

**Update** THREE.js r.146

Sharing complete example using `BufferGeometry` since `Geometry` is deprecated since [r.125](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401), while following the wonderful example of @prisoner849 and discourse thread [Plane intersects mesh with three.js r125](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/plane-intersects-mesh-with-three-js-r125/34543/5)

Example includes clipping the geometry based on the intersection points which are used to generate the `LineSegments`.

Can also instead create a `Plane` from the `PlanarGeometry` `Quanternion` and `Normal`

```
let localPlane = new THREE.Plane();
let normal = new THREE.Vector3();
let point = new THREE.Vector3();

normal.set(0, -1, 0).applyQuaternion(planarGeometry.quaternion);
point.copy(planarGeometry.position);
localPlane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(normal, point).normalize();**
```

Function updates `Lines` with current intersection based on the current position of the `PlanarGeometry`

```
let lines = new THREE.LineSegments(
  new THREE.BufferGeometry(),
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    linewidth: 5
  })
);

function drawIntersectionLine() {
  let a = new THREE.Vector3();
  let b = new THREE.Vector3();
  let c = new THREE.Vector3();

  const isIndexed = obj.geometry.index != null;
  const pos = obj.geometry.attributes.position;
  const idx = obj.geometry.index;
  const faceCount = (isIndexed ? idx.count : pos.count) / 3;

  const clippingPlane = createPlaneFromPlanarGeometry(plane);
  obj.material.clippingPlanes = [clippingPlane];

  let positions = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < faceCount; i++) {
    let baseIdx = i * 3;
    let idxA = baseIdx + 0;
    a.fromBufferAttribute(pos, isIndexed ? idx.getX(idxA) : idxA);
    let idxB = baseIdx + 1;
    b.fromBufferAttribute(pos, isIndexed ? idx.getX(idxB) : idxB);
    let idxC = baseIdx + 2;
    c.fromBufferAttribute(pos, isIndexed ? idx.getX(idxC) : idxC);

    obj.localToWorld(a);
    obj.localToWorld(b);
    obj.localToWorld(c);

    lineAB = new THREE.Line3(a, b);
    lineBC = new THREE.Line3(b, c);
    lineCA = new THREE.Line3(c, a);

    setPointOfIntersection(lineAB, clippingPlane, positions);
    setPointOfIntersection(lineBC, clippingPlane, positions);
    setPointOfIntersection(lineCA, clippingPlane, positions);
  }

  lines.geometry.setAttribute(
    "position",
    new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positions), 3)
  );
}

function setPointOfIntersection(line, planarSrf, pos) {
  const intersect = planarSrf.intersectLine(line, new THREE.Vector3());
  if (intersect !== null) {
    let vec = intersect.clone();
    pos.push(vec.x);
    pos.push(vec.y);
    pos.push(vec.z);
  }
}
```

Example [CodePen](https://codepen.io/emptybox/pen/QWxGyRz)