# How to use Three.js plane

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, plane

I'm trying to use three.js plane to get the distance from a point to a plane.

I have three points a,b,c, that I calculate the normal like so:

```
    const v = a.clone().sub(c);
    const u = b.clone().sub(c);
    const normal = u.cross(v);
```

Then

```
const plane = new THREE.Plane(normal, (?))
```

What are you supposed to give in the second argument?

From the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Plane):

> the negative distance from the origin to the plane along the normal vector. Default is 0.

What does that mean?

If I place there the distance of one of the points a,b,c to (0,0,0) (positive and negative distance), like `const dist = a.distanceTo(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0))`, then if I do:

```
plane.distanceToPoint(a);
```

I'm getting a huge number and not zero, the same happens if I leave that argument empty.

So how can I place that plane at its correct place so that the distance to points on that plane will be zero as it should?

Comment: why not to use `.setFromCoplanarPoints(a, b, c)` method of `THREE.Plane()` as you already have three coplanar points?

Comment: I didn't see that function in the docs, I'll try. @prisoner849

Comment: @prisoner849 yes it looks a lot better now, thanks. You can write this as the answer.

Comment: @kuhaku [This change](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/efccbfee0d27bf44503454d3d9f292b76a243f3e) has not made it into production yet, but it should clarify things for you.

Comment: It should clarify that it's just the distance from (0,0,0), "origin" and "signed" can be confusing. @WestLangley

Comment: What, exactly, do you think it shoud say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have three coplanar points, you can use `.setFromCoplanarPoints(a, b, c)` method of `THREE.Plane()`.

An example of using it is in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353447/4045502).