# How to get a polygon from a Triangulated Face in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, geometry, polygon

I looked up around the Net if this someone had the same problem.
I'm working with three.js. I have a 3DObject, which may contain holes. The faces are triangulated. Let say I want to see it from above: my objective is to get a Polygon which represents the perimeter of the top face.(that means for me, no more triangulated faces but only 1 Polygon). My approach till now was the following: I used the Three.js function "EdgesGeometry" over a shape geometry to get a collection of unsorted lines which, connected with a self-written function, build a closed Polygon. The Problem begins with holes. Because after I use the "EdgesGeometry" function, I don't know if lines are the outer lines of a polygon or the inner lines around the hole.
So I have a couple of question:

- How can I know if a ShapeGeometry made of triangulated shapes contains a hole? (nice to know but it does not solve the problem)
- Is there a function which transforms a Triangulatedshape (ShapeGeometry) in a Polygon with or without holes? (of course, they would be a different structure or definition)
- May I have taken the wrong way to get to my objective?

My ideal result would look like this:

- a collection of sorted segments which describe the perimeter of the polygon and 0 to n collections of sorted segments which describe the holes.
- a collection of sorted points which describes the perimeter of the polygon and 0 to n collections of sorted points which describe the holes.

All these questions are referred to a three.js environment.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Thank you for your attention.
Have a good day.

P.S. I have considered to use point-in-poly algorithms after my function in case of holes, but I think it is not performant and complexity (O notation) would raise.

Comment: Didi I get it correctly, that you have a sequence of co-planar points and want to build a shape from them?

Comment: No, the opposite. I have a Three.js  triangulated Shape and I want to get the Polygon (perimeter) of the Shape. The point/ triangles are co-planar yes.

Comment: Isn't it an option to intersect your object with a plane and get contours?

Comment: I don't think since the internal points of the shape, also all the points of the triangles are also found in the intersection. If I understood what you meant.

Comment: :) That's why it's better to illustrate a question with explanatory pictures. Also, you can ask your question [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/).