# 3D Slicing web app Javascript and Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, slice

I am developing a web application to estimate the cost of a 3D printing model with three.js and also do other stuff.

I have easily calculate bounding box and volume of object and I am now approaching slices.
Following this question I have managed to get intersections with a plane: [Three JS - Find all points where a mesh intersects a plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348495/three-js-find-all-points-where-a-mesh-intersects-a-plane/42353447) and I put the function inside a for loop that appends to a three.js group.

```
// Slices
function drawIntersectionPoints() {
    var contours = new THREE.Group();
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        a = new THREE.Vector3(),
        b = new THREE.Vector3(),
        c = new THREE.Vector3();
        planePointA = new THREE.Vector3(),
        planePointB = new THREE.Vector3(),
        planePointC = new THREE.Vector3();
        lineAB = new THREE.Line3(),
        lineBC = new THREE.Line3(),
        lineCA = new THREE.Line3();

        var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50,50);
        planeGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
              color: "lightgray",
              transparent: true,
              opacity: 0.75,
              side: THREE.DoubleSide
        }));
        plane.position.y = i;
        scene.add(plane);


      var mathPlane = new THREE.Plane();
      plane.localToWorld(planePointA.copy(plane.geometry.vertices[plane.geometry.faces[0].a]));
      plane.localToWorld(planePointB.copy(plane.geometry.vertices[plane.geometry.faces[0].b]));
      plane.localToWorld(planePointC.copy(plane.geometry.vertices[plane.geometry.faces[0].c]));
      mathPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(planePointA, planePointB, planePointC);

      meshGeometry.faces.forEach(function(face) {

          mesh.localToWorld(a.copy(meshGeometry.vertices[face.a]));
          mesh.localToWorld(b.copy(meshGeometry.vertices[face.b]));
          mesh.localToWorld(c.copy(meshGeometry.vertices[face.c]));
          lineAB = new THREE.Line3(a, b);
          lineBC = new THREE.Line3(b, c);
          lineCA = new THREE.Line3(c, a);
          setPointOfIntersection(lineAB, mathPlane);
          setPointOfIntersection(lineBC, mathPlane);
          setPointOfIntersection(lineCA, mathPlane);
      });

        var lines = new THREE.LineSegments(pointsOfIntersection, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xbc4e9c,
            lineWidth: 2,
      }));
        contours.add(lines);

        function setPointOfIntersection(line, plane) {
          pointOfIntersection = plane.intersectLine(line);
          if (pointOfIntersection) {
              pointsOfIntersection.vertices.push(pointOfIntersection.clone());
          };
        }; 
    };

    console.log(contours);
    scene.add(contours);
```

And this is what I see:
The for loop works and I visualise all the planes and also the lines inside the group but only the first intersection is showing in the canvas (pink).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5IuW.png)

Many thanks.

Comment: Where and how do you declare and initialize `pointsOfIntersection` variable? Would be great to have [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `.updateMatrixWorld(true)` on your `plane` object after you set its `y`-coordinate in the loop:

```
plane.position.y = i;
plane.updateMatrixWorld(true);
scene.add(plane);
```

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/5jxbq9hp/) example.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much.