# threejs line follow along geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am looking for a way to draw a (poly)line around an object. I have a mesh where I need lines projected on so I can use this for my project.

For example I have this geometry: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_skin.html

No horizontal around the head. Going over the nose, ears and should be closed. I have thought about raycasting to the center of the object every 1 degree. But this will lose accuracy.

This is a really bad picture but gives the idea, I want to try and get the red line around the geometry as a new polyline: 
[image]

Is there a way I can get a polyline out of the geometry at a specific height?

Comment: just a wild idea, sure it is not the way to go : create a red rope then send it to your guy it will surround (and stick to ?) him

Comment: Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353447/4045502), pay attention to the line with UPD info.

Comment: @prisoner849 that is indeed what i'm looking for. Does it also work with an open geometry? In my example. I don't have the "back of the head".

Comment: The result is just a geometry with pairs of points, used with `THREE.LineSegments()`, so theoretically it should work with so-called an "open" geometry too :)