# Three.js plane inherit topography from set of meshes

Tags: three.js

**What's working:**
I have a solution for loading in topography using terrain tiles. Each tile occupies a plane as mesh. The image on the plane can then be any map tile source. Each plane mesh is a child of an object3d and offset accordingly to create the overall terrain.

**The Question:**
I am not sure the best way to go about having an irregular shape inherit 3d surfaces. This shape could be drawn or imported as KML. Is there a way to use a vertex shader to inherit the topography? I would like the topography as a mesh so that I can interrogate the topography of the shape. In this way it is different from using a shader to paint the surface as a mesh result is needed.

I do not yet have code for this to share as I do not know where to start. Vertex shader? Constructive solid Geometry?

[image: Image of three js with 3d map topography and an example of a polygon shape draped over the surface.]

Comment: First, I thought to advice to look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353447/4045502), but now I'm not sure that got what you want to achieve. Can you post the question on the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) and put more details about the problem?

Comment: I can yes, thanks. Mods, if an answer comes up there, I will repost the answer here for the stack community.