# How do I calculate a perimeter of a flattened mesh?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to calculate the perimeter of a custom shaped 3d object but I'm totally in a black room :(

Actually I've managed to get the EdgeHelper of the mesh by doing this:

```
    var helper = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0x00ff00 );
    helper.material.linewidth = 2;
    helper.scale.x = 0.001;
```

But now... what can I do to have the perimeter?

May you please point me to the right direction? Any tip would be more than appreciated :)

Comment: Could you put an explanatory pic of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I imported a 3ds file and I've a mesh like this one:

[link](https://www.espositoriatos.it/fianco.png)

I just would like to calculate the perimeter of this object (which is a flatten solid)

Comment: Specifically for such objects, you can find points of intersecion of the mesh with a plane and calculate the sum of length of all lines. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353447/4045502)

Comment: Yeah I had a try with that solution but I think my result is composed by A LOT of points, so I end up receiving the “Maximum call stack size exceeded” exception :(

That's why I was searching for an alternative path or some other tips...