# Meassure circumference of an object at a given point

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image]

I have a 3d object of any shape and I want to measure it's circumference along a given axis, in the case of my example, the y axis where y = 5.

How would I take this measurement with three.js?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your question at the moment. Are you looking for a general solution for any object? are you looking for a solution just for cylinders, depending on their rotation? Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Updated the question. It would need to be able to measure the circumference of an object of any shape.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353447/4045502). Just cut a geometry with a plane and find the sum of lengths of segments.