# How to get the global position of a vertex of a skinned mesh in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In Three.js, we are now able to get the global position of a vertex of a **non-skinned** mesh thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495089/how-to-get-the-absolute-position-of-a-vertex-in-three-js), but how can I get the global position of a vertex of a **skinned** mesh with bones and morph targets?

For example, how can I print `(2.5, 1.5, 0.5)` in the following situation?
`mesh.geometry.vertices[0]` is originally at `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)`.
Then, `bones[1]` moves the vertex to `(2.5, 0.5, 0.5)`.
Finally, morphing moves the vertex to `(2.5, 1.5, 0.5)`.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 200);
camera.position.z = 3;
camera.position.y = 2;
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
geometry.morphTargets.push({name: "morph", vertices: []});
for (const vertex of geometry.vertices) {
  geometry.skinIndices.push(new THREE.Vector4(vertex.x < 0 ? 0 : 1, 0, 0, 0));
  geometry.skinWeights.push(new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0));
  geometry.morphTargets[0].vertices.push(vertex.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)));
}

const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  skinning: true,
  emissive: 0xffffff,
  wireframe: true,
  morphTargets: true
});

const mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, material);

const bones = [new THREE.Bone(), new THREE.Bone()];
for (const bone of bones) {
  mesh.add(bone);
}

const skeleton = new THREE.Skeleton(bones);
mesh.bind(skeleton);

bones[0].position.x = -2;
bones[1].position.x = 2;
mesh.morphTargetInfluences[0] = 1;
scene.add(mesh);

// This code assigns (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) to pos,
// but I want to know the code which assigns (2.5, 1.5, 0.5) to pos. 
const pos = mesh.geometry.vertices[0].clone().applyMatrix4(mesh.matrixWorld);
console.log(`(${pos.x}, ${pos.y}, ${pos.z})`);

(function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a "global position" for a skinned mesh? Say you a simple skinned cube with one face weighted to 100% bone #1 and the opposite face weighted to 100% bone #2.  Put bone #1 at 0, 0, 0, and bone #2 at 0, 0, 1000. What's the global position? What answer do you want?

Comment: @gman Updated the question. I am also wondering whether it is suitable to call this kind of position "global position".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is what I did to try to figure this out. I'm too lazy to check if it works for all cases but ...

First I used the [Shader Editor extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shader-editor/ggeaidddejpbakgafapihjbgdlbbbpob?hl=en) and then I ran [a skinned example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_skinning_simple.html) and using the shader editor I looked at the generated shader

[image]

Looking at the vertex shader the relevant part of the shader is

```
#ifdef USE_SKINNING
    mat4 boneMatX = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.x );
    mat4 boneMatY = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.y );
    mat4 boneMatZ = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.z );
    mat4 boneMatW = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.w );
#endif
#ifdef USE_SKINNING
    mat4 skinMatrix = mat4( 0.0 );
    skinMatrix += skinWeight.x * boneMatX;
    skinMatrix += skinWeight.y * boneMatY;
    skinMatrix += skinWeight.z * boneMatZ;
    skinMatrix += skinWeight.w * boneMatW;
    skinMatrix  = bindMatrixInverse * skinMatrix * bindMatrix;
    objectNormal = vec4( skinMatrix * vec4( objectNormal, 0.0 ) ).xyz;
#endif

vec3 transformedNormal = normalMatrix * objectNormal;
#ifdef FLIP_SIDED
    transformedNormal = - transformedNormal;
#endif


vec3 transformed = vec3( position );

#ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
    transformed += ( morphTarget0 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ];
    transformed += ( morphTarget1 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 1 ];
    transformed += ( morphTarget2 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 2 ];
    transformed += ( morphTarget3 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 3 ];
    #ifndef USE_MORPHNORMALS
    transformed += ( morphTarget4 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 4 ];
    transformed += ( morphTarget5 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 5 ];
    transformed += ( morphTarget6 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 6 ];
    transformed += ( morphTarget7 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 7 ];
    #endif
#endif

#ifdef USE_SKINNING
    vec4 skinVertex = bindMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
    vec4 skinned = vec4( 0.0 );
    skinned += boneMatX * skinVertex * skinWeight.x;
    skinned += boneMatY * skinVertex * skinWeight.y;
    skinned += boneMatZ * skinVertex * skinWeight.z;
    skinned += boneMatW * skinVertex * skinWeight.w;
    transformed = ( bindMatrixInverse * skinned ).xyz;
#endif
```

So translating that into JavaScript here's what I came up with

First off you need the scene to have all its world matrices
and the skeleton updated.

```
scene.updateMatrixWorld();
skeleton.update();
```

Then

```
  // These are so we can avoid doing allocations
  // in the inner loop.
  const position = new THREE.Vector3();
  const transformed = new THREE.Vector3();
  const temp1 = new THREE.Vector3();
  const tempBoneMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  const tempSkinnedVertex = new THREE.Vector3();
  const tempSkinned = new THREE.Vector3();

  const bindMatrix = mesh.bindMatrix;
  const bindMatrixInverse = mesh.bindMatrixInverse;

  for (let vndx = 0; vndx < mesh.geometry.vertices.length; ++vndx) {
    position.copy(mesh.geometry.vertices[vndx]);
    transformed.copy(position);

    for (let i = 0; i < mesh.geometry.morphTargets.length; ++i) {
      temp1.copy(mesh.geometry.morphTargets[i].vertices[vndx]);
      transformed.add(temp1.sub(position).multiplyScalar(mesh.morphTargetInfluences[i]));
    }

    tempSkinnedVertex.copy(transformed).applyMatrix4(bindMatrix);
    tempSkinned.set(0, 0, 0);

    const skinIndices = geometry.skinIndices[vndx];
    const skinWeights = geometry.skinWeights[vndx];

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      const boneNdx = skinIndices.getComponent(i);
      const weight = skinWeights.getComponent(i);
      tempBoneMatrix.fromArray(skeleton.boneMatrices, boneNdx * 16);
      temp1.copy(tempSkinnedVertex);
      tempSkinned.add(temp1.applyMatrix4(tempBoneMatrix).multiplyScalar(weight));
    }

    transformed.copy(tempSkinned).applyMatrix4(bindMatrixInverse);
    transformed.applyMatrix4(mesh.matrixWorld);
```

Example:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 2, 0.1, 200);
camera.position.z = 3;
camera.position.y = 2;
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:document.querySelector('canvas')});
renderer.setSize(512, 256, false);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
geometry.morphTargets.push({name: "morph", vertices: []});
for (const vertex of geometry.vertices) {
  geometry.skinIndices.push(new THREE.Vector4(vertex.x < 0 ? 0 : 1, 0, 0, 0));
  geometry.skinWeights.push(new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0));
  geometry.morphTargets[0].vertices.push(vertex.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)));
}

const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  skinning: true,
  emissive: 0xffffff,
  wireframe: true,
  morphTargets: true
});

const mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, material);

const bones = [new THREE.Bone(), new THREE.Bone()];
for (const bone of bones) {
  mesh.add(bone);
}

const skeleton = new THREE.Skeleton(bones);
mesh.bind(skeleton);

bones[0].position.x = -2;
bones[1].position.x = 2;
mesh.morphTargetInfluences[0] = 1;
scene.add(mesh);

const putMeshesAtSkinnedVertices = (function() {

  // These are so we can avoid doing allocations
  // in the inner loop.
  const position = new THREE.Vector3();
  const transformed = new THREE.Vector3();
  const temp1 = new THREE.Vector3();
  const tempBoneMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  const tempSkinnedVertex = new THREE.Vector3();
  const tempSkinned = new THREE.Vector3();

  return function putMarkersAtSkinnedVertices(mesh, scene, marker, markerMaterial, markers) {
    const bindMatrix = mesh.bindMatrix;
    const bindMatrixInverse = mesh.bindMatrixInverse;
    const geometry = mesh.geometry;
    const vertices = geometry.vertices;
    const morphTargets = geometry.morphTargets;
    const skeleton = mesh.skeleton;

    for (let vndx = 0; vndx < vertices.length; ++vndx) {
      position.copy(vertices[vndx]);
      transformed.copy(position);

      for (let i = 0; i < morphTargets.length; ++i) {
        temp1.copy(morphTargets[i].vertices[vndx]);
        transformed.add(temp1.sub(position).multiplyScalar(mesh.morphTargetInfluences[i]));
      }

      tempSkinnedVertex.copy(transformed).applyMatrix4(bindMatrix);
      tempSkinned.set(0, 0, 0);

      const skinIndices = geometry.skinIndices[vndx];
      const skinWeights = geometry.skinWeights[vndx];

      for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        const boneNdx = skinIndices.getComponent(i);
        const weight = skinWeights.getComponent(i);
        tempBoneMatrix.fromArray(skeleton.boneMatrices, boneNdx * 16);
        temp1.copy(tempSkinnedVertex);
        tempSkinned.add(temp1.applyMatrix4(tempBoneMatrix).multiplyScalar(weight));
      }

      transformed.copy(tempSkinned).applyMatrix4(bindMatrixInverse);
      transformed.applyMatrix4(mesh.matrixWorld);

      // create them the first time this is called
      let markerMesh = markers[vndx];
      if (!markerMesh) {
        markerMesh = new THREE.Mesh(marker, markerMaterial);
        markers[vndx] = markerMesh;
        scene.add(markerMesh);
      }

      markerMesh.position.copy(transformed);
    }
  }
}());


// Make sure all matrices are up to date
scene.updateMatrixWorld();
skeleton.update();

const marker = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
const markerMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
const markers = [];

putMeshesAtSkinnedVertices(mesh, scene, marker, markerMaterial, markers);

(function render() {
//  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

I did test it with [this sample](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_morph.html) and it seemed to work.

[image]